# Cant query into outfile

Tags: mysql

This is an example query below;

```
select * from device limit 1
into outfile 's:\\data.xls'
```

I am trying to outfile to s:\\ on my server but keep getting presented with the error below;

Can't create/write to file 's:\\data.xls' (Errcode: 2)

However when i run the query below it saves it fine to the c:\\

```
select * from device limit 1
into outfile 'C:\\new.xls'
```

Comment: in query you are using s:\\ while description says s://

Comment: I have amend it now

Comment: your server is windows based? Also check whether the mysql user has permission to write on s:\\

Comment: Error 2 is *file not found* (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` in Windows.h). Your server may not have the same drive mappings as you. Use UNC filenames instead of drive letters. Your server has a C: drive (as do most Windows-based computers). You have a serious security hole there, however; your server is configured poorly if it allows you to write files to the root of C:\. You should speak to your network admins about that potential breach.

Comment: Yeah server is windows based and i have permission to write there

Comment: I have tried the UNC \\shpsvr01.shp.local\\Shared\\new.xls but it still get the same error